# Encoding problem while transferring data via sockets python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, utf-8

I am new to socket programming and learning the basics.
This code works fine on one computer. But, when tested using two different computers, it is raising errors related to encoding/decoding.
I've tried different encodings, but none of them worked.
The encodings I've tried and their errors respectively are given below after the code.

I hope someone can help me with it.
Thanks

server.py

```
import socket
import threading

SERVER="192.168.1.4"
PORT=5051
ADDR=(SERVER, PORT)
SIZE=1024
FORMAT='utf-8'

server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)

def getfile(conn: socket.socket, addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] Connected : {conn}")
    connected=True
    while connected:
        fname=conn.recv(SIZE).decode(FORMAT)
        if fname=="!disconnect":
            connected=False
            break
        print("[RECV] Receiving the file name")
        file=open(fname,"wb")
        conn.send("[ACK] Received the file name".encode(FORMAT))
        print("Receiving the file data")
        data=conn.recv(SIZE)
        while data:
            file.write(data)
            file.flush()
            if len(data)<SIZE:
                break
            data=conn.recv(SIZE)
        conn.send("[ACK] Received the data".encode(FORMAT))
        file.close()
    print(f"[DISCONNECTED] {conn} - disconnected")
    conn.close()


def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"Server is listening on : {SERVER}")
    while True:
        conn, addr=server.accept()
        threading.Thread(target=getfile, args=(conn, addr)).start()
        print(f"[CONNECTIONS] Number of active connections : {threading.active_count()-1}")


print("[STARTING] Server is starting...")
start()
```

client.py

```
import socket
import threading

SERVER="192.168.1.4"
PORT=5051
ADDR=(SERVER, PORT)
SIZE=1024
FORMAT='utf-8'
client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(ADDR)

def send():
    file=open("tpic.jpeg","rb")
    client.send("nfile.jpeg".encode(FORMAT))
    msg=client.recv(SIZE).decode(FORMAT)
    print(f"[SERVER] {msg}")
    data=file.read(SIZE)
    while data:
        client.send(data)
        if len(data)<SIZE:
            break
        data=file.read(SIZE)
    msg=client.recv(SIZE).decode(FORMAT)
    print(f"[SEVRER] {msg}")
    file.close()

send()
client.send("!disconnect".encode(FORMAT))
```

**Errors**

1. FORMAT='utf-8'
   Initially,

```
line 17, in getfile
fname=conn.recv(SIZE).decode(FORMAT)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Now,

```
line 17, in getfile
fname=conn.recv(SIZE).decode(FORMAT)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf4 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

and

```
line 17, in getfile
fname=conn.recv(SIZE).decode(FORMAT)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

2. FORMAT='utf-16'

```
line 17, in getfile
fname=conn.recv(SIZE).decode(FORMAT)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 12-13: illegal UTF-16 surrogate
```

3. FORMAT='ISO-8859-1'

```
line 22, in getfile
file=open(fname,"wb")
ValueError: embedded null byte
```

Comment: Basically the same problem as with the linked question: you assume that a single send matches a single recv. This assumption is wrong, since TCP is an unstructured byte stream and not a structured stream of messages. This wrong assumption messes up what you read so you ultimately end up trying to decode data  which were not encoded or where parts of a multi-byte encoded are missing.

Comment: You're sending 10 bytes of filename but receiving 1024.  The filename is going to contain a bunch of junk you didn't intend.